# What was this homebrew monster class based on That Damn Crab and other crab memes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, content-identification

**WARNING: The content of this question is potentially disturbing and contains references to animal abuse**

I remember reading a homebrew class some time ago (within a few years) that has been based on various crab memes like "[this kills the crab](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-kills-the-crab)" represented as something along the lines of "this kills the human", or an ability to wield a melee weapon like a crab from [this video](https://youtu.be/0QaAKi0NFkA), though I am not sure that the latter was actually there.

- Every few levels, the crab would choose one ability from a list, and a new list of abilities was given. One of the abilities, for sure, was an ability to steal a dead creature's natural armor bonus like a hermit crab.
- Other abilities gave the crab's claws various enhancement bonuses, gave the crab itself increased speed and/or natural armor, etc.
- Some abilities of that class were based on a [Monstrous Crab](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fw/20040221a), notorious for being largely under-CRed.
- It was published on a site with a comment section where many improvements were suggested for the author's concept.

I found it long ago when googling for crab jokes, but I can't find it now, and I've been trying for at least a few months.

***What was this homebrew crab class, and where can it be found?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this one: [**Awakened Monstrous Crab**](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=539.0)

It seems to match your description. The A*wakened Monstrous Crab* gradually increases its STR and CON score while it advances in level and it can chose from an array of different class features or feats. The *Hermit Crab* ability you described also exists, it can be chosen at level 4.